# How can I get server and stream key from AWS MediaLive

Tags: amazon-web-services, live-streaming, obs, aws-media-live, aws-elemental

I need to configure live streaming using OBS studio software, live streaming has already been setup on AWS using ElementalMediaLive(auto wizard). but I am unable to figure out the way to find the `server address` and `stream key` which are required the configure the OBS studio.
can some one please guid me where can I find the above required information into AWS panel?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is the "stream name" in the rtmp ingest point URL. The format would be something like

rtmp://domain:1935/live/**streamname**

stream key in OBS is **streamname**

For detail, please refer to page 7 and 8 of this pdf: https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/fb644351560d8296fe6da332236b1f8d61b2828a/2020/04/14/Connecting-OBS-Studio-to-AWS-Media-Services-in-the-Cloud-v2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/media/connecting-obs-studio-to-aws-media-services-in-the-cloud/

Especially this document:

https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/fb644351560d8296fe6da332236b1f8d61b2828a/2020/04/14/Connecting-OBS-Studio-to-AWS-Media-Services-in-the-Cloud-v2.pdf

Where it says:

> STEP C: CONFIGURE THE APPLIANCE
>
> 1. Launch OBS Studio on the source system. Choose Settings to open the settings window. Choose Stream to access the streaming settings.
> 2. Complete the fields:
>
> - For Stream Type, choose Custom Streaming Server.
> - For URL, copy one of the endpoint URLs from the input you created in    Step B. Remove the /<stream_name> at the end of the URL.
> - For Stream key, type the stream name.
> - Leave the Use authentication box unchecked.
> - Choose Apply to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, 
but I am unable to figure out the stream name :) because there are so many `/`

Comment: In the AWS Elemental Media Live console, click on Inputs -> Select your desired input and have a look at the `Endpoints`. These should be in a format: `rtmp://<IP>:<PORT>/somename/someinstance`. Remove the `/someinstance` part, which is the Application instance from Step B / 6. of the PDF i gave you. Then you should be good to go with the remaining Endpoint URI as your `Server` in OBS.

Answer (score 0):

What OBS refers to as "stream key" is the App Instance.

Regards,